# Access Child class variables in Parent class

Tags: python, django

I have a Parent class and a inherited child class, I would like to know how to access the child class variable in my Parent class..

I tried this and it fails -

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print x

class Child(Parent):
    x = 1;            

x = Child();
```

Error:-

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

This question is in relation to Django forms where we inherit the form class 
and declare some class variables.

For example:-

My form looks like this

```
from django import forms

class EmployeeForm(forms.Form):
      fname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
      lname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I believe the form fields are considered as class variable and somehow passed to the parent class..

Comment: x is a Class variable, e.g. `print(Child.x)` and `print(self.x)` will print the same variable. Did you mean to make this a Class variable?

Comment: But this doesn't have anything to do with child and parent classes. if you defined `x = 1` directly on Parent at the class level, that *still* wouldn't work. You seem to be misunderstanding Python classes completely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right. Besides, if you are sure that `x` will always be implemented in inherited classes, why don't you define it in the parent class?

Comment: I can define it but Im trying to understand how Django FORMS child class works.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is his defense, Django makes use of pseudo-metaclasses to "collect" these attributes -- trying to learn python from Django is not the best approach.

Comment: OK, so why don't you post your actual problem?

Comment: @DanielRoseman:-- I dont have any issues and its for my educational purpose.I'm trying to understand how django forms class variable(fname & lname) is being accessed in its Parent class - Form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django does this with metaclasses.  ([Relevant Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py))

Here's a distilled example of the relevant code:

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __repr__(self): 
        return "Form(%s)" % (', '.join(map(repr, self.args)),)


class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        field_list = []
        for k,v in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(v, Field):
                field_list.append(v)

        cls = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

        cls.fields = field_list

        return cls


class Form(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta


class MyForm(Form):
    fe1 = Field("Field1", "Vars1")
    fe2 = Field("Field2", "Vars2")
    x = "This won't appear"


form_fields = MyForm.fields
print(form_fields)
```

There are many questions on here about Python metaclasses ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)), so I won't try to re-explain the concept.

In this case, when you create the class `MyForm`, each of the class attributes are checked for being instances of `Field`.  If they are, they're added to a list (`field_list`).

The class is created, then an attribute `.fields` is added to the class, which is `field_list`, the list of `Field` elements.

You can then access the form fields through `<FormSubclass>.fields` or in the case of this example, `MyForm.fields`.

---

**Edit:**

It's worth noting that you can accomplish very similar functionality, without the metaclass syntactic sugar with something like:

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __repr__(self): 
        return "Form(%s)" % (', '.join(map(repr, self.args)),)


class Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fields = None

    def fields(self):
        if self._fields is None:            
            field_list = []
            for k in dir(self):
                v = getattr(self, k)
                if isinstance(v, Field):
                    field_list.append(v)
            self._fields = field_list

        return self._fields


class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        Form.__init__(self)
        self.fe1 = Field("Field1", "Vars1")
        self.fe2 = Field("Field2", "Vars2")
        self.x = "This won't appear"


form_fields = MyForm().fields()
print(form_fields)  # [Form('Field1', 'Vars1'), Form('Field2', 'Vars2')]
```

Comment: @user1050619 No problem, I added a bit of example-specific discussion at the bottom of the answer.  I may update it a few more times in the next few minutes if I see places I could expand on.

Comment: Shoo-wee! That link was a big read - definitely watched my own eyes glaze over in the computer screen. Honestly your first code snippet really helped me to understand what was happening! Thank you kind Samaritan!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : you *dont* access subclasse's attributes from a parent class - because the parent class can not know what attributes a child class might have.

Long answer : ... unless the parent class defines a protocol allowing subclasses to let the parent class knows about at least part of it's own attributes.

Django's form framework (as well as django's orm FWIW) use such a protocol: the base `Form` class has a custom metaclass that collects the `form.fields` declared in a subclass - and do quite some black magic. FWIW, Django is oss so you could have answered the question yourself just reading the source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py

Answer (score 2):

This might not help you in regards to Django Forms, but another alternative is to work with [abstract classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). You would exchange attributes with methods/properties. It also prevents you from using the parent class by itself.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Parent(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.x)

class Child(Parent):

    @property
    def x(self):
        return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child_instance = Child()    # prints "1"
    parent_instance = Parent()  # fails
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to `self.x` to access `Child` class variables:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.x)

class Child(Parent):
    x = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child_instance = Child()
```

Comment: And then you have an `AttributeError` for any instance of `Parent` that doesn't define `x` as a class or instance attribute...

Answer (score -1):

Well, if I got you right... Maybe you're thinking of getting a field from the child class to work on the parent class. Well, that's polymorphism and it's done by overriding the parent class.
Let's assume you have :
A parent has x, now to increase x from the child and make it reflect in the parent, check the code below to get it.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def Print(self):
        print(f"{self.x}")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        Parent.__init__(self, x)
        x += 1
        self.x = x

""""""

c1 = Child(2)
c1.Print()

#output: 3

""""""

c2 = Child(8)
c2.Print()

#output: 9
```